# Javascript for loop returns "copy" as value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array which starts out empty - `var currentChatSessions = []`;

It is then populated - `currentChatSessions[privateSessionID]=targetUser;` (this is a string, ex 'myName')

I have a function that iterates through the array -

```
function checkExisting(from){//check for existing chats with that user
        var oldId=0;
//*         
        for(var index in currentChatSessions) { 
            console.log('checkExisting index: ' + index);
            console.log('checkExisting data: ' + currentChatSessions[index]);

            if (currentChatSessions[index] == from){
                oldId=index;
                console.log('check Existing: ' + oldId);
            }
            break;

        }
//*/        
        console.log('check existing oldId: ' + oldId);
        return oldId;
    };
```

and logs this to the console - `checkExisting index: copy` and 
`checkExisting data: function (){var i=new Array();for(var I=0,l=this.length;I<l;I++){i[I]=this[I]}return i}`

I know that strings are passed in as variables, as I call them back in other places, and the correct strings are returned.

Why would it be returning a function instead of a string??

Thanks for the help

Comment: Don't use `for...in` for arrays, use a regular `for`.

Comment: it may not be understanding what is currentChatSessions[index] ..use a simple for loop for(var index=0;index<currentChatSessions.length;index++)

Comment: can I iterate `(i=0; i<variable.length; i++)` on an associative array? It doesn't seem like it's working. How would I get the index value with that method?

Comment: Also, I saw multiple online tutorials and other resources using for...in for arrays

Comment: you're using a regular array. we call 'associative arrays' 'hashes' or 'objects'. you want to do what I say in my answer

Comment: I never figured out how to get the for() loop working right - I'm not sure what the problem was. I did figure out how to get the data I needed in a different way. Thanks to all for the suggestions and advice.

Answer (score 4):

`for (var x in array)` will iterate all properties on the array set to enumerable, not just array elements.  That can include methods who's value will be code which could explain what you are seeing. I would guess that you may be using some code (either library or just code) that adds methods to your array in a way that makes them enumerable.

You should iterate arrays by index only from `0` to `.length - 1`.  There are several ways to do that, but the classic method is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

For Arrays, you have to use another way of looping - in stead of `for ... in`:

```
for(var index=0;index<currentChatSessions.length;index+=1) { /*...*/ }
```

Otherwise, other [enumerable properties](http://www.2ality.com/2011/07/js-properties.html) of the Array are included in the loop, leading to the unpredictable results you experienced.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you really want to do is:

```
var currentChatSessions = {};
```

Note the nipple brackets instead of braces.

You probably have a library that extends the Array prototype. When you do for-in on an object, it will show you all methods on that object. Someone is probably doing `Array.prototype.something = function() {};` so when you loop over any array with `for in` you'll get that function.